# Uh-oh, the galactic bank just got blown up - what now?

Tags: science-fiction, economy, space-colonization, geopolitics

I'm running a sci-fi tabletop game, and the current big bad the party is hunting down is a group of freedom fighters with big ideas, and a MacGuffin relic capable of large-scale destruction. The big bad’s plan? Destroy the galactic banking system.

**Let me give some context:**

This campaign takes place in a homebrew universe, centred around a collection of six neighbouring galactic empires. They each have a claim to roughly two to ten solar systems, with travel between them being possible for centuries, and ubiquitous for the last century. While there have been numerous large-scale conflicts in the past, it has been over half a century since the last war, and the six empires are (on average) on good terms with each other.

During this time, a centralized financial system sprung into existence, originating from the center-most empire. This empire's systems are few, but they are heavily defensible and easily reachable by only three or four system-hops from any other system. As such, they rapidly became hubs for galactic trade, and there was an agreement that it was in everyone's best interests they remain neutral, with all other parties pledging their protection.

The aforementioned financial system provides a standardized form of electronic currency known as Credits (which are universally accepted), acts as a banking service, and hosts the galactic stock market. Virtually all the administration, book-keeping, and data storage is located on a single planet at the heart of the empire, and if anything were to happen to that planet, it would essentially wipe out all traces of this system.

Since its inception, it has been deemed completely impossible for this system to be interfered with. The security around the administrative centres is ludicrously thorough, and the planet itself is surrounded by a shield generator that prevents orbital bombardment. Furthermore, even if it were to fall under siege, any attempted acts of aggression upon the planet would be met with retaliation from all other parties, and would only shoot the would-be invaders in the foot.

**How does this relate to the initial prompt?**

The previously mentioned MacGuffin that belongs to the big bad is essentially an energy weapon capable of glassing an entire planet, with a method of deployment that cannot be negated by any amount of physical defence. Its activation is also nearly instantaneous, so there are basically no suitable countermeasures once it is within range.

My player's confrontation could go both ways - either they defeat the big bad, or the big bad succeeds, up-ending the status quo and becoming a recurring foe they'll need to get stronger and eventually defeat. If through a series of bad decisions, a stroke of bad luck, or both, it becomes apparent the plan will go off without a hitch, I want it to happen, instead of pulling the punch. Because of that, I want to properly think through the consequences long before they might actually happen.

**The actual question**

What would be the immediate consequences of this event in terms of the daily lives of citizens of the galaxy? What would corporations and governments do to mitigate the effects of this event?

I'd appreciate as detailed answers as possible, and references to applicable historical parallels. I'm not much of an economist, social scientist, or historian, so I figured I'd crowdsource it!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question is way too broad for the site. You're asking for whole-of-society snapshots at multiple intervals extending out a century. Folks tend to close questions of that form. I'd recommend trying to limit this question significantly to avoid that. And I hope you will, because I find this interesting and hope to see some form of it attract answers.

Comment: Welcome Evan. We have a longstanding strict one question per post policy. If you can focus the question, then ask subsequent questions in their own threads, perhaps adding a hyperlink to the main one here with all the details, then that would work much better within our rules.

Comment: @Tom That's a good point - I changed the actual question at the bottom to ask more about the initial state of affairs. Think this is narrow enough of a scope to get some decent responses?

Comment: @AngryMuppet Ah, ok, just narrowed it down further

Comment: Is there faster than light communication? What are people's lives like in the first place? What's the state of the government, do they have contingency plans for this scenario? (They'd be fools not to, and hey, maybe they're fools)

Comment: @AngryMuppet Yep, they have FTL communication, with the total transmission delay being no more than a couple of hours from one end of the region to the other. Life is very easy for the majority, with abundant food and luxury, but there is still a sizeable lower class burdened by large amounts of debt. As for backup plans, most who brought up such a scenario were laughed out of the room, so the most in-depth contingency anyone had was basically "impose martial law, I guess?"

Comment: You have not defined what you mean by a "*centralized financial system*" nor what that system does, nor why it would be evil, so you're asking for a lot of opinions about what we think you might possibly mean by that term. In the current world economy, "centralized financial systems" usually refer to institutions that secure the currency from manipulation, and institutions that regulate banks and markets to prevent abuse and theft. None of those goals are evil.

Comment: Ultimately, its your world, so you can do what you want with it.  But having worked with bank infrastructure, it is almost inconceivable to me that an interplanetary bank would keep all its records exclusively on one planet.  Data redundancy to a ridiculous degree is already the default behaviour, and we've only got the one planet.

Comment: Problem with your scenario is that the information in your comment to @AngryMuppet that comms can take up to a few hours is incompatible with a fully centralised banking system.  Either cash is used for the majority of transactions everywhere or the banking system is decentralised - when someone goes to make an everyday purchase it's not plausible to wait hours for the EFTPOS / credit card request to be sent to the Planet of Central Banking and a reply to be sent.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on complete total irremediable lack of understanding of how a bank actually works. Basically, blowing up a bank (for example, the beautiful 19th century headquarters of CEC Bank in Romania) will have no effect whatsoever except *maybe* a few minutes interruption of electronic services. The IT systems which provide core banking services are distributed; the data is religiously backed up offsite, to secure locations.

Comment: It looks like your world has been built and you're asking what would be the effect of an event on your society. Questions asking what would be the effect of X on society are not permitted on this site.

Comment: @AlexP Asking a question where the answer is clear as skies is worth a downvote (-> lack of research), but does not make it a candidate for closure alone :). I'm personally standing on the lack of details -How does this bank work here?- and lack of focus : it falls in the "what if X happened?"-, as per the [help-center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). @ Evan S You should focus the question on a specific part of society (B2B trade, the nearest star marketplace...), and explain a bit more why this bank is central in all galaxy for us to answer accurately ;).

Comment: The Milky Way Galaxy contains at least 100 biliion star systems.  You write: "This campaign takes place in a homebrew universe, centred around a collection of six neighbouring galactic empires. They each have a claim to roughly two to ten solar systems, with travel between them being possible for centuries, and ubiquitous for the last century." If only one star out of a thousnd is useful for civilization the six empire s will rule about 12,000 to 60,000 stars combined,  or about 0.0000006 of the stars in the galaxy.  They seem more like interstellar empires than galactic empires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Galactic Banking Plant has several functions.  In no particular order of importance:

- Issuance of Credits, E-Currency accepted throughout the galaxy
- Galactic Stock Exchange, where the galaxy can bet on companies to succeed or fail
- Financial Sector of the Central Empire, their economic heart

There will be issues that resonate throughout this incredibly audacious act.  The effects will fundamentally vary based on where you are in galaxy.  And make no mistake, it will affect far more than just economic matters.

Beware the Wall of Text that lies ahead for I have tried to be thorough in all aspects of the fallout.

Yes, I know banks don't work this way, but I will try to work within the scope of the question as it was typed when I answered it.

#### Banking Logistics

Based on the comments and the question itself, nobody will wait 4+ hours (2 each way) to validate a local purchase, and that goes double for a small ones -- just look at people now that use a debit card for everything no matter how small the purchase.

Me personally, I'm not even waiting 15 seconds to use a debit card for 5 bucks -- I'm just using cash and being done with it.  For that much, it's probably out and ready before my stuff is checked out.

No, if needed, they will have a server on each planet that accepts Credits and contains their resident's bank accounts.  This way, purchases made will not take hours to verify and people can go on their way.  This is doubly so because as an e-currency, one can't just carry Credit notes about and pay in cash.

The Planet Server will synchronize periodically (likely multiple times daily depending on bandwidth) with the Central Planet to make sure all accounts are updated with the central records with relevant transactions being beamed to the needed planets.  This would also save them money and increase profits and efficiency, and they will be all over that.

There likely isn't much, if any, in redundancy because an attack on these servers would be equivalent to attacking the banking planet itself which was deemed to be inconceivable.  It could even be that they're the Banking Empire's embassies for that reason.  Plus, it would fit with the idea of believing themselves unassailable.

If they don't do that for their customers, then expect local cash to be even more relevant than you would think it would be in such a setting.  Cash being king in a sci-fi setting might actually be refreshing.

Alternatively, this central bank idea was solely designed for commerce between empires as a form of standardization so the average person using Credits for everyday purchases was not even considered.  The delay in processing is fine and is an acceptable part of doing business and is planned on.  Invoicing and all that stuff.

**Why this is a BAD IDEA**

By the way, The part of me that works with data as a job cringes hard at the utter lack of redundancy in this system by the way.  This is *begging* for a failure like this.  I would have backups off-world given the scope of the empire, or at the very least in a doomsday bunker server like we have seeds in one now on our world.

Admittedly, I agree with the premise of attacking electronically over physically

This will be an issue repeatedly brought up by every IT guy on the planet unless it is specifically forbidden to be talked about in meetings -- That and cyber-security.  Plus, lag time will pull customers away from your banks and into the local ones if they don't do anything about it.

#### Currency Matters

You have stated that the Credit is a galactic standard currency.  You do not state how many of the six empires have phased out their own currencies in favour of these Credits.

For a comparison, consider the Euro.  With its inception within the EU, countries with the Union have moved to the singular currency.  How much each individual country has moved to it over their own currencies is a topic I do not know much about save that Britain steadfastly held onto their Pounds.

**Local Dough**

How the average person reacts will likely depend on if they use their system's currency or Credits.  Those that still have their own currency will be generally unaffected in day to day matters as they still use their empire's currency, backed by however their particular empire backs their money.

These people likely don't use Credits on a daily basis so will not feel it immediately.  They will start to feel it when the SpacMart has trouble stocking off-planet merchandise because all off-planet purchases have to be done in Credits as a policy or some equally ridiculous thing.

But so long as the planet can sustain itself with its own food, that should be less of a concern and not really a humanitarian crisis.  Those city planets may have a problem though.

**Credit Crisis**

Those that solely rely on credits may have an issue.  As stated in the comments, it is unlikely that *absolutely everything* is on the banking planet, but it is likely a key hub in the Credits model and was designed that way so that people don't get ideas.

But without the hub of the Central Planet and due to their hubris, account information can't be updated outside the planet that you live on at best and not at all at the worst.  Interplanetary purchases grind to a halt because the transaction can't carry through from one system to another.  Automated payments off-planet likewise stop because they too are automated to go through the Hub.

Essentially, the system is impaled and what is left is each planet's Credit system that may or may not exist and whatever backups may exist by crazy doomsday preppers.

**Corporate Life**

Corporations likely have a headquarters on the planet of origin, and a copy of all of their relevant financial documents there.  While people can't play the stock market from half a galaxy away, they will still own the shares and should still be able to theoretically receive dividends.  The issue will be how to pay them out effectively, or even if they can.

This does not even get into how to pay staff that are systems away effectively when the central bank has been obliterated and it was the only hub in the galaxy.  There will be a corporate scramble to get an effective bank back online

Or to resurrect each empire's banking system in the short term.  Maybe even build their own and capitalize on a tragedy.

**On Contacts**

Also a consideration, if the PCs know anyone on the Banking Planet that they know is being targeted, they might warn them.  If they are in the right position, they might be able to back up some things and escape the planet so not *everything* is lost.

Likewise, if their contacts is the Banking Empire themselves, they might have warning and start scrambling.  Of course, that might make the problem worse and not better.

#### The Banking Empire

Congratulations, your villain has likely crippled an entire empire!  Plus, one of your players will get to quote Star Wars unironically!

Sarcasm aside, your villain has just murdered millions of people most likely.  Depending on the level of automation in the system, that number could possibly reach in the billions.  Several genocides are likely committed in the extinction of indigenous wildlife to the planet that can't survive in other places.

The Banking Empire's administrative heart has just been glassed.  With their faith in it being unassailable, it likely means that many key bureaucratic jobs were there.  This could translate into a paralyzation and/or crippling of the empire's government in the short to medium term.  While the capital is likely (hopefully) on a different planet, I would not be surprised if a good amount of the administration of the Empire happened here near all the banking technology and the money.

Also, your Banking Empire has just had war declared on them by ... well ... terrorists.  Perhaps not in the strictest dictionary definition of the word, but it is essentially a declaration of war on them.  They will be galvanized by such an audacious attack, and be fearful of how it was done.

For a comparison, consider the destruction of the World Trade Centre in 2001 combined with a the financial crash of 2008, all on one event.  It's still nowhere near what is going on here, but it is a start.

**Other Concerns**

This does not even go into the value of whatever other exports they have.  If any of the native wildlife has some manner of medicinal use in the galactic community as a whole, it's now gone unless it somehow can survive The Glassing or is being bred in captivity on other planets in zoos and the like.

#### Diplomatic Nightmares

The biggest thing is the diplomatic nightmare that this will cause among the Six Empires.  Either by treaty or unspoken convention, the other five will rouse to defend the Banking Empire from this attack.  And make no mistake, they were attacked and hit hard.

However, this is not a Seventh Empire with a system or three of their own, or a extra-galactic threat that is flexing its power on a planet.  It's disaffected freedom fighters, likely of all peoples, rising up and doing something about a problem that they think they have.  They are many, but they are not one relatively speaking.

It is not something that any one empire can solve by glassing a rebel planet in retaliation.  It is a slow and arduous search for the people who did it, and anyone connected to them.  It is intelligence and counterintelligence to try and find the bolt holes and the plans of these people to see if they can repeat the action that the MacGuffin created before it hits them.

It is the accusations that any one of the other five empires have not done their part to prevent this.  Even if ultimately it could not be prevented just due to the surprise and the audacity of it.  There is the actual threat of this shattering the fragile mutual defence alliance that had held for half a century.

It is the flaring up of tensions and accusations from wounds that are still there from wars and conflicts in the past.  Conspiracies of collusion and of programs that were terminated by may not actually have been will arise.  Trust between the empires may erode in the immediate aftermath of The Glassing, as well as during the search as they find out who is part of what empire.

Fifty years may sound like a long time, but that is grandparents telling stories of living in the war to their grandchildren.   Speaking for myself, in 2000 I could hear about WWII from my grandmother and that war would have been over for 55 years at the turn of the century.

#### The PCs

Who's hired your PCs to go after these people?  That will determine how they themselves are treated.

In the event that the Banking Planet gets glassed, they may find themselves basically persona non grata in a heck of a lot of places in the galaxy.  Simply because they couldn't stop it from happening, or because people have fallen for the conspiracy that they *let* it happen.  Either way, they could effectively find themselves banished by the peoples until they are either forgotten about or catch the people that did it.

Alternatively, they may find themselves on the vanguard of the hunt.  As the group that knows these people best they are basically ordered by six empires to find them or die trying.

Either way, I suspect reaction to them will be polarizing to anybody that knows that they were there.

#### Mitigation Measures

So how does a government mitigate such a problem?  Well, by not putting all your data on one planet realistically.  Redundant servers throughout the Banking Empire to backup data and to work as a failsafe in case something does happen to the main systems.

Putting a server on each planet that handles that planet's affairs to aggregate and collect the data would be a way to prevent a total collapse.  At least data can be UPS'd across the galaxy if need be.

Corporations will already do this as a matter of course.  Given that the scope of each empire and that FTL is a thing as per the comments, there is no reason why secure backups for any corporation would be on the same planet as its head office.  Plus, they'll need those backups for tax purposes.

Answer (score -2):

**The Problem:**

Nobody knows who has how much money, or what payments have (or have not) been made. Nobody can process payments, nobody is credit-worthy. For day-to-day troubles, you can google the results of credit card or ATM failures like the one in [Canada](https://www.reuters.com/business/media-telecom/rogers-communications-services-down-thousands-users-downdetector-2022-07-08/). Possibly compounded if there is no physical currency for small transactions.

**The Solution:**

The various governments might guarantee the values deposits in the retail banking system to prevent a breakdown while they create in-system clearing mechanisms between banks. They would risk a certain amount of abuse and fraud, and individual hardships. ("My money is in the bank at Alpha Centauri, I swear!" -- "Sorry, the deposit insurance only covers Sirius banks.")

This might effectively create local currencies, which are not interchangeable. There would need to be forensic audits for larger (or more dodgy) accounts.

**The Problem:**

The transfer of wealth/money *between* countries is actually quite complicated. Once upon a time they shipped gold, but that had [problems](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9060/how-did-the-gold-of-the-new-world-cause-the-spanish-empire-to-collapse/9094#9094). Today there is [SWIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIFT), and the [Iran sanctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banking_and_insurance_in_Iran#Sanctions) are an example of what happens if it goes down.

**The Solution:**

Recreate something like SWIFT, after in-system banking has been stabilized.

Comment: This answers shows the same misconception about how banks really work as the question. The IT systems which provide core banking services are distributed. The data is *religiously* backed up off-site to secure locations. It is really *hard* to erase the banking data by blowing stuff up. It is much easier to mess with it using software methods than with crude methods such as bombs.

Comment: @AlexP, the OP specified an architecture where all communications between banks are **routed** through one planet. They presumably assume that one planet is big enough. Each bank may believe in the integrity of their backups, but without central routing how should one bank believe another?

Comment: The only instance of the character sequence "rоut" on this page is on your comment. Anyway, logically centralized — physically distributed is a design paradigm older than the hills.

Comment: @AlexP, I wrote "transfer" and "process." And I took the design decision by the OP to centralize that on one planet as the starting point. One planet could be reasonably believed to offer enough separation.